# Java collection/map apply method equivalent?

Tags: java, collections, apply

I would like to apply a function to a Java collection, in this particular case a map. Is there a nice way to do this? I have a map and would like to just run trim() on all the values in the map and have the map reflect the updates.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

With Java 8's lambdas, this is a one liner:

```
map.replaceAll((k, v) -> v.trim());
```

For the sake of history, here's a version without lambdas:

```
public void trimValues(Map<?, String> map) {
  for (Map.Entry<?, String> e : map.entrySet()) {
    String val = e.getValue();
    if (val != null)
      e.setValue(val.trim());
  }
}
```

Or, more generally:

```
interface Function<T> {
  T operate(T val);
}

public static <T> void replaceValues(Map<?, T> map, Function<T> f)
{
  for (Map.Entry<?, T> e : map.entrySet())
    e.setValue(f.operate(e.getValue()));
}

Util.replaceValues(myMap, new Function<String>() {
  public String operate(String val)
  {
    return (val == null) ? null : val.trim();
  }
});
```

Comment: Hey erickson - where can I learn about this syntax: Map<?, String> map ?? I am just learning java and have not come across anything like that.. any direction would be appreciated!

Comment: @jamesemanon It means that the map you pass to this method can have any type of key, but the value must be a `String`. You can get the basics from the [Java Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/wildcards.html).  [Angelika Langer's Generic FAQs](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/JavaGenericsFAQ.html) has much more detailed information about all aspects of Java Generics.

Answer (score 11):

I don't know a way to do that with the JDK libraries other than your accepted response, however Google Collections lets you do the following thing, with the classes `com.google.collect.Maps` and `com.google.common.base.Function`:

```
Map<?,String> trimmedMap = Maps.transformValues(untrimmedMap, new Function<String, String>() {
  public String apply(String from) {
    if (from != null)
      return from.trim();
    return null;
  }
}
```

The biggest difference of that method with the proposed one is that it provides a view to your original map, which means that, while it is always in sync with your original map, the `apply` method could be invoked many times if you are manipulating said map heavily.

A similar `Collections2.transform(Collection<F>,Function<F,T>)` method exists for collections.

Answer (score 2):

Whether you can modify your collection in-place or not depends on the class of the objects in the collection.

If those objects are immutable (which Strings are) then you can't just take the items from the collection and modify them - instead you'll need to iterate over the collection, call the relevant function, and then put the resulting value back.

Answer (score 2):

Might be overkill for something like this, but there are a number of really good utilities for these types of problems in the [Apache Commons Collections](http://commons.apache.org/collections/) library.

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>(); 
map.put("key1", "a  ");
map.put("key2", " b ");
map.put("key3", "  c");

TransformedMap.decorateTransform(map, 
  TransformerUtils.nopTransformer(), 
  TransformerUtils.invokerTransformer("trim"));
```

I highly recommend the [Jakarta Commons Cookbook](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/059600706X) from O'Reilly.

Comment: Just wanted to mention the immutable version in Apache Commons Collections library:

CollectionUtils.collect(Collection inputCollection, Transformer transformer)

Answer (score 2):

I ended up using a mutation of @erickson's answer, mutated to:

- return a new `Collection`, not modify in place
- return `Collection`s with elements of type equal to the return type of the `Function`
- support mapping over either the values of a map or the elements of a list

Code:

```
public static interface Function<L, R> {
    L operate(R val);
}

public static <K, L, R> Map<K, L> map(Map<K, R> map, Function<L, R> f) {
    Map<K, L> retMap = new HashMap<K, L>();

    for (Map.Entry<K, R> e : map.entrySet()) retMap.put(e.getKey(), f.operate(e.getValue()));

    return retMap;
}

public static <L, R> List<L> map(List<R> list, Function<L, R> f) {
    List<L> retList = new ArrayList<L>();

    for (R e : list) retList.add(f.operate(e));

    return retList;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to iterate over all the entries and trim each String value. Since String is immutable you'll have to re-put it in the map. A better approach might be to trim the values as they're placed in the map.

Answer (score 1):

I have come up with a "Mapper" class

```
public static abstract class Mapper<FromClass, ToClass> {

    private Collection<FromClass> source;

    // Mapping methods
    public abstract ToClass map(FromClass source);

    // Constructors
    public Mapper(Collection<FromClass> source) {
        this.source = source;
    }   
    public Mapper(FromClass ... source) {
        this.source = Arrays.asList(source);
    }   

    // Apply map on every item
    public Collection<ToClass> apply() {
        ArrayList<ToClass> result = new ArrayList<ToClass>();
        for (FromClass item : this.source) {
            result.add(this.map(item));
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

That I use like that :

```
Collection<Loader> loaders = new Mapper<File, Loader>(files) {
    @Override public Loader map(File source) {
        return new Loader(source);
    }           
}.apply();
```

Answer (score -2):

You could also take a look at Google Collections

Comment: Kind of vague... at least provide a link and a description/example of how to use Google Collections to solve the problem?