# Hibernate queries call toString() method

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, hql, jpql

I have a list of names: `List<Name>`, `Name` has two methods:

- `toString()` returns "Name: Tom"
- `getName()` returns "Tom"

To query the database for persons with certain names, I'd do

```
// Query a single database entry
Query query = em.createQuery("FROM person WHERE name = :name");
query.setParameter("name", names.get(0).getName());
```

When I want to query multiple entries (using `WHERE ... IN (...)` I'd have to do this:

```
// Convert the list of name instances to a list of strings
List<String> nameStrings = new ArrayList<String>(names.size());
for (Name name : names) {
  nameStrings.add(name.getName());
}

// Query multiple database entries
Query query = em.createQuery("FROM person WHERE name in (:name)");
query.setParameter("name", nameStrings); // JPA
query.setParameterList("name", nameStrings); // Hibernate
```

Do I have to build a second list? I'd rather do this:

```
// Query a single database entry
Query query = em.createQuery("FROM person WHERE name = :name");
query.setParameter("name", names.get(0));
```

and

```
// Query for multiple database entries
Query query = em.createQuery("FROM person WHERE name in (:name)");
query.setParameter("name", names); // JPA
query.setParameterList("name", names); // Hibernate
```

Comment: You can define name as primary key and avoid transfering name.getName() to nameString, just pass names, as you would like. I do not suggest using toString() in query case, it is misleading.

Comment: above the second last code block

Comment: @JMelnik Thanks, you are right in this specific case. But the problem persists, when the Name object is not an @ Entity. I edited the question accordingly. I hope now it's straight to the point! Sorry.

Comment: The problem is, that `Person.name` is actually of type `Name`. But with `WHERE person.name in (:name)` and `query.setParameter("names", names)` hibernate calls `toString()` when building the query. I thought, I could provide some serialization method in class `Name` or tell hibernate how to build the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer is yes, you need to build the second list. You need to provide a `List` of `String`s (or rather a `Collection`), a `List<Name>` will never match this. I'd recommend making some kind of utility method that takes a `List<Name>` and return a `List<String>` of the names.

```
public static List<String> toNameStrings(List<Name> names) {
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(names.size());
    for (Name name : names) {
        list.add(name.getName());
    }
    return list;
}
```

I haven't been able to test the following, and I'm not sure I want to recommend it in any way, but I *think* you could make a `List` implementation that would return different object types depending on the state it's in. Using this you'd be able to do something like `list.setStringMode(false)` to use it as a `List<Name>` (though Generics are going out the window at this stage, they'll all be returned as `Object`), then `list.setStringMode(true)`, to use it as a `List<String>`. It would look something like the following:

```
public class NameAndStringList extends ArrayList<Object> implements List<Object>
{
    private boolean stringMode = false;

    @Override
    public boolean add(Object object)
    {
        return super.add(toName(object));
    }

    // Do the same for add(index, element)
    // Do the same for set(index, element)
    // Do the same for remove(object)

    @Override
    public boolean addAll(Collection<? extends Object> collection)
    {
        final List<Name> convertedCollection = new ArrayList<Name>();
        for (Object object : collection)
        {
            convertedCollection.add(toName(object));
        }
        return super.addAll(convertedCollection);
    }

    // Do the same for addAll(index, collection)
    // Do the same for removeAll(index, collection)
    // Do the same for retainAll(index, collection)

    @Override
    public boolean contains(Object o)
    {
        return super.contains(toName(o));
    }

    // Do the same for containsAll(collection)
    // Do the same for indexOf(object)
    // Implement Iterator that checks the stringMode variable before returning value.
    // Override all iterator methods to retrieve custom Iterator implementation.
    // Override subList(fromIndex, toIndex) to make subList be an instance of NameAndStringList as well.

    @Override
    public Object get(int index)
    {
        if (stringMode)
        {
            return ((Name) super.get(index)).getName();
        }
        return super.get(index);
    }

    // Implement setStringMode(boolean)

    protected Object toNameString(Object object)
    {
        if (object instanceof Name)
        {
            // Convert to String here
        }
        return object;
    }

    protected Name toName(Object object)
    {
        if (object instanceof String)
        {
            // Convert to Name here.
        }
        return object;
    }
}
```

Note that this relies on you being able to convert a `String` to a `Name` as well as vice-versa, but you could always get rid of that bit if you know you'll always populate it yourself using `Name` instances. The general idea here is that the `List` stores `Name` instances, but is free to return `String` instances since it's a `List<Object>`. Again, I'm not sure I'd recommend this approach, but it should meet your requirements, or at least as close as I can get atm.

Comment: OK. But that would mean, that I have to change the type of `Person.name` from `Name` to `String` (!) because else I get this exception:`Parameter value element [...] did not match expected type [Name]`

Comment: I didn't mean to use the same custom `List` implementation for both queries - they require different types and so they have to be, you simply can't have a type that is both `Name` and `String` (since `String` is final). You could however provide a constructor for your custom `List` that takes the `List<Name>` as a parameter and initialises based on that.

Comment: @steffen I've added a different potential solution, although it's not pretty.

Comment: Thank you very much! But then I'd probably prefer http://stackoverflow.com/a/744472/1296402 instead, because your solution is not that reusable. Valid question: is this solution shorter? `List<String> nameStrings = Util.transform(names, new Function<Name, String>() {
 @Override
 public String operate(Name value) {
  return value.getName();
 }
});
`

Comment: Depends on what you mean by shorter. Looks to me like there's more code to provide each time you're using the method. It's also harder to read and (very marginally) slower to execute, but you'll likely have more of it auto-generated by an IDE. Overall I wouldn't consider there to be much in it.