# Array modification in Java (changing array "resolution")

Tags: java, arrays

I want to create a function that changes the size of an array of integers while maintaining its "shape".

The purpose is to speed up calculations for an FFT.

It returns a new array of size `y` with each element an average of the elements it would "cover" in the old array. For instance, if I have an array `w` with 3 elements, and want to create another array `z` with 2 elements, the first element would be: `z[0] = (1 * w[0] + 0.5 * w[1]) * 2 / 3`, and the second element would be: `z[1] = (0.5 * w[1] + 1 * w[2]) * 2 / 3`. It's kinda like changing the "resolution" of the array. (Of course, with small numbers, rounding risks losing information, but I need it for fairly large numbers where a couple of digits wont matter.)

It feels like it's a pretty straightforward question, yet I've spent too much time in vein. I do have some code, and although I get it to Almost work I think I'm on the wrong track (way too many lines). Basically, it's looping through the original array, and calculating how to divise each element, and keeping track of where to put it with a local variable.

Also, my searches all turned up stuff like dynamically changing size of arrays and such, which isn't what I want.

So, here's a possible skeleton:

```
public int[] the_function (int[] w, int y) {
    int[] z = new int[y];

    // Some code looping through the array

    return z;
}
```

Comment: You want to make the array larger by interpolating values, right? What if `y < w.length`?

Comment: We would need more data about "idea" you are tying to implement. What do you mean by `"cover" in the old array`? On what rule you decided that `z[0] = (1 * w[0] + 0.5 * w[1])...` but `z[1] = (0.5 * w[1] + 1 * w[2])...`? Why `w[1]` have always `0.5 * ` before it?

Comment: Please post what you have tried.

Comment: It seems to me that it's up to you to develop an algorithm.

Comment: ... or [search SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/744435/java-collection-map-apply-method-equivalent)?

Comment: @hd1 this will not accomplish what Fred was requesting....

Comment: @ Matt: Inversely, I want to shrink the array, so y must be < w.length (sorry, unclear about that)

@ Pshemo: It's not always the case, only for this example. Imagine taking an image twice with the only difference being the resolution. What I want to achieve is the step from the bigger picture to the smaller (except, I'm not doing photos).

@ John: I'll work a bit more, and depending on if I write my own algorithm or use someone else's, I'll post it more finished (I got some ideas from the replies)

Answer (score 1):

So you want to apply a filter to an array? This is a naive implementation... 
I think the key is to be smart on how you encode the filter ...  which i will do by representing it a series of floats representing the percent of the orginal value i want to apply to the output value. This is pretty standard when it come to filters.

```
public static int[] applyFilter( int[] from , float[] filter ) { 
    if (filter.length > from.lenth){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Filter to large to apply to array!");
    } 

    int [] to = new int[from.length + 1 - filter.length];

    for ( int i = 0; i < from.length + 1 - filter.length; i++) { 
        float newValue = 0.0f;

        for( int j = 0; j < filter.length; j++){
           newValue += filter[j] * from[i+j]; 
        }

        to[i] = Math.round(newValue);
    }
    return to;

}
```

And to call the filter, like you specified in the question....

```
public static void main (String ... args){
    float[] filter = new float[] { 0.66f, 0.66f }; 
    int[] from = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};

    int[] to = applyFilter(from, filter);
    for (int i : to){
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```

Handling the case of from[1] being scaled by 1/2, can be hadled by preprocessing the array then applying the filter second. Like so:

```
 public static void main (String ... args){
    float[] filter = new float[] { 0.66f, 0.66f }; 
    int[] from = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};

            // Preprocess to apply static scalars to the source array.
            int[] frompp = from.clone();
            frompp[1] = Math.round((float) from[i] / 0.5f);

    int[] to = applyFilter(from, filterpp);
    for (int i : to){
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **lcm**, least common multiple, to use integral arithmetic.
You image both source array (w) and target array mapped/scaled on a grid of the
least common multiple.

```
public static int gcd(int a, int b) {
    while (a != b) {
        if (a > b) a -= b; else b -= a;
    }
    return a;
}

public static int lcm(int a, int b) {
    return a * (b / gcd(a, b);
}

One then can achieve a high precision in averaging.
For image scaling ideal and fast.
For your purpose `double` math will do, I think, and saves a bit on index juggling.
```