# Change "resolution" of an array

Tags: arrays

Imagine a given array is a quantized representation of a continuous function. I want to change the "resolution" of this quantization - change the length of the array but preserve its "shape". Scale the array, in a sense.

Rough example:

```
[1, 20, 40, 60, 80, 100] -> [1, 50, 100]
```

You could imagine this as a quantization of a the straight line graph y=x.

What I'm looking for is some term for this that would let me search for an algorithm quickly. Is there such a term?

> Note: not the same as [Array modification in Java (changing array "resolution")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16525094/array-modification-in-java-changing-array-resolution), although on the same topic. The person there didn't ask for a term for this process, and none of the answers are what I'm looking for.

Comment: Seems under-specified. Why `[1, 50, 100]` as opposed to e.g. `[10.5, 50, 90]`? One obvious approach is to use e.g. a cubic spline through the points and then resample the spline.

Comment: Maybe search for "convert points into a function". Once you have a function, you can grab as many points from it as you'd like (i.e. to create your set of points with a different "resolution"). Another search example might be "fit curve to points." C.f. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curve_fitting