# Java equivalent of apply functions in R

Tags: java, r, lapply

I've been programming in R for around a year now, and am just starting to teach myself Java. One thing I've loved about R is the family of apply() functions (e.g. sapply, mapply, apply etc.).

I was wondering if Java had equivalent functions, or if anyone had written these up in Java - I may be able to give some of these a basic go myself, but I wouldn't be able to do much in terms of the optimisation they seem to have (i.e. sapply(FUN, X) seems much faster than for(i in 1:length(X)) FUN(X[i]) in many cases).

If not, am I thinking about this badly e.g. perhaps you don't tend to need to apply some function, FUN to each element of a vector often since Java is object-oriented, so in typical problems where you'd want to use these, Java's not your best bet, or there are other ways of approaching it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java collection/map apply method equivalent?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/744435/java-collection-map-apply-method-equivalent)

Comment: IMHO this is no duplicate because now there is a solution (lambda expressions) and 6 years ago there wasn't.

Answer (score 1):

The [functional additions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html) in Java 8 should address your concerns.

Answer (score 0):

Previous to java 8 java is not a functional language.

A functional language is a language where it is possible to pass a function as an argument to another function.

The introduction of [Lamba expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html) solve this problem.

If you can't use java 8 the only possibility is to create an interface with only one method (apply for example) and manually call the apply method when needed (see for example [how swing works to handle events like click](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html)).